# How to modify rootfs of an unprivileged LXC container?

Tags: lxc, container

I have configured for namespaces for unprivileged LXC containers using this docuement

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-unpriv

I can create and start containers using `lxc-create` and `lxc-start` without using sudo.

But now I want to modify the container before starting it, but I cannot do it because rootfs is owned by user 100000:

`vagrant@lxci-host:~$ ls -l $HOME/.local/share/lxc/u1/
total 8
-rw-rw-r--  1 vagrant vagrant  616 Nov 22 12:38 config
drwxr-xr-x 21  100000  100000 4096 Nov 22 12:38 rootfs`

How can I workaround this?

The container was created using this

```
lxc-create -t download -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. By using `lxc-usernsexec` command to execute my container modifying commands.

Man page quote:

```
NAME
       lxc-usernsexec - Run a task as root in a new user namespace.

SYNOPSIS
       lxc-usernsexec [-m uid-map] {-- command}

DESCRIPTION
       lxc-usernsexec can be used to run a task as root in a new user namespace.
```

Example for custom `/etc/hosts` file

```
lxc-usernsexec cp hosts $HOME/.local/share/lxc/u1/rootfs/etc/hosts
```

Comment: Cool. I built a whole `/etc/subuid` parser exactly for this purpose...